# Open most recent workbook in a folder on SharePoint document library

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I would like to open the most recent workbook in SharePoint document library. The file is saved as an archive that I need to access to pull information from.

I have tried a bit of VBA script that allowed me to access the file through CAFs but since all my folders have been moved online to 365 I need a new way to access the most recent archive workbook in the folder.

```
'Force the explicit delcaration of variables
Option Explicit

Sub OpenLatestFile()

     'Declare the variables
     Dim MyPath  As String
     Dim MyFile  As String
     Dim LatestFile  As String
     Dim LatestDate  As Date
     Dim LMD  As Date

     'Specify the path to the folder
     MyPath = "file location on sharepoint"

     'Make sure that the path ends in a backslash
     If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

     'Get the first Excel file from the folder
     MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsm")

     'If no files were found, exit the sub
     If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
         MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
         Exit Sub
     End If

     'Loop through each Excel file in the folder
     Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

         'Assign the date/time of the current file to a variable
         LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

         'If the date/time of the current file is greater than the latest
         'recorded date, assign its filename and date/time to variables
         If LMD > LatestDate Then
             LatestFile = MyFile
             LatestDate = LMD
         End If

         'Get the next Excel file from the folder
         MyFile = Dir

     Loop

     'Open the latest file
     Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
```

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to use Dir:

```
Const PATH As String = "\\companyHere.sharepoint.com\Departments\Blah\Stuff\"

Dim f

f = Dir(PATH & "*.xlsx")

Debug.Print f
Debug.Print FileDateTime(PATH & f)
```

works for me.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I amended my code but I am still getting error f = Dir(PATH & "*.xlsm") run time error 52 bad file name or number.

Comment: Does the DIR have a problem with http:\\?

Comment: You dpn't need http

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem. I had to use the URL path.